# Workflow Permissions not working as expected

Tags: drupal, permissions, workflow

I have Workflow Permissions configured but they don't seem to be working properly. I'm trying to allow the author to View posts in the Paid state but not edit. Here is the permission matrix for this: http://screencast.com/t/dqqKwc1kcd

The result of this configuration allows the author to both View and Edit.

If I uncheck View, the author can no longer view or edit. It seems to be half working. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try unchecking the "edit own" permission for that content type in the place where all the drupal permissions are.

Comment: Also, try clicking the "Rebuild permissions" button in admin/content/node-settings

Answer (score 0):

After permissions changes, rebuild your site permissions, at: admin/reports/status/rebuild